# Ranking between two strings

Tags: combinatorics

For the word "BOOKKEEPER". It's sorted representation is "BEEEKKOOPR" How can I find the different permutations of the word between "BEEEKKOOPR" and "BOOKKEEPER"?

similar example:

For "BBAA"

```
AABB - 1
ABAB - 2
ABBA - 3
BAAB - 4
BABA - 5
BBAA - 6
```

6 - 1 = 5 So there are 5 words before "BBAA"

"BEEEKKOOPR" would be number 1. "BOOKKEEPER" would be some distance away. I'm not sure how to go about this as I believe this is a combinatorics problem and I don't have much experience with the subject.

Comment: How are the permutations being ordered?

Comment: I'm pretty sure lexicographically

Comment: @Bananarama correct

Comment: this is a difficult problem, even when all letters are different there is no simple formula.

Answer (score 1):

discounting B (which must lead every string), there are 9 symbols.
we can rank

(B = 0)

E = 1

K = 2

O = 3

P = 4

R = 5

now, for BOOKKEEPER
we can include every combination that gives 2 or fewer for the first digit: 
3 "1"s and 2 "2"s

5 * 8!
+ 
all valid combinations where 3 is the first digit

if 3 is the first digit, and 2 or fewer is the second digit, include all combinations, so:
5 * 8!
+
4 * 7!
+ 
all valid combinations starting with 33

if the next digit is a 1, of which there are 3, include it

5 * 8!
+
4 * 7!
+ 
3 * 6!
+ 
all valid combinations 332

if the next digit is a 1, of which there are 3, include it

5 * 8!
+ 
4 * 7!
+ 
3 * 6!
+ 
3 * 5!
+ 
all valid combinations 3322

the next digit must be a 1, and the digit after that must be a 1, so really its

all valid combinations 332211

if the next digit is 1, include all values:

5 * 8!
+ 
4 * 7!
+ 
3 * 6!
+ 
3 * 5!
+ 
2!
+ 
all valid combinations 3322114

of which there is only 1: 332211415 ie, BOOKEEPER

so the number of values below BOOKEEPER is

5*8! + 4*7! + 3*6! + 3*5! + 2! + 1, and between BOOKEEPER AND BEEEKKOOPR

is

5*8! + 4*7! + 3*6! + 3*5! + 2!

since we just subtract off the extra 1.

At least, that's how I'd solve it.

Comment: My [code](http://codepad.org/erej14aG) says your count is wrong.